# Funny symbol came out from \footnote command when using Adobe Garamond Pro font

Tags: footnotes

I tried to use the \footnote{} command for thanks in a paper but the symbol was funny, not what I wanted. I switched over to \thanks{} command but again it didn't help. The symbol was the one for mail, i.e., looking like an envelope symbol.

Specifically, this code didn't work as it produced the funny symbol:

```
\title{\textbf{Title\footnote{We thank ABC. All errors remain our own.}}}
```

Could you please help?

Here's the full code sniplet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Use "svgnames" in place of "dvipsnames" to have more colors.

%\usepackage[english]{babel} % Multi-language support
\usepackage[round,sort&compress, authoryear]{natbib}
% \addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}} % Change default "Bibliography" to my favorite "References"
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % To get Table Heading number BOLD
\usepackage{indentfirst} %All paragraphs are indented
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} % Modify default footnote markers

% Install my favorite fonts with math fully supported
\usepackage[]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % If you find that fontspec is incorrectly changing the maths font when it shouldn’t be, apply the no-math package option to manually suppress its selection of the maths fonts.
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Kerning=Uppercase, Numbers=Proportional]{Adobe Garamond Pro} % Option: Ligatures=TeX
\setmathrm{Adobe Garamond Pro} 
% some additional (optional) typographic enhancements
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{selnolig} % of course, this won't do much for latin lipsum text :-)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Put the following at LAST %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Use "hidelinks" option to make links black; put "linktocpage" as an option will show red link around page numbes in TOC only, not the whole text and page numbers



% \usepackage[hyphens]{url} % I need this whenever I have too long an URL in footnote

\begin{document}
%\sloppy
\title{\textbf{Title\footnote{We thank ABC. All errors remain our own.}}} 

\author{
    Author Full Name\thanks{
            University Name, Place, Country. \href{mailto: authoremail@hotmail.com}{authoremail@hotmail.com}
        }
    }

\vfill

\date{First version: March 2014 \\This version: July 2016 }

\maketitle

% Blind title
\begin{center}
    \LARGE {\textbf{Blind Title}}

    \vspace{1cm}
    Abstract
\end{center}

\noindent This paper examines a couple of things...

\vspace{1cm}
\noindent JEL Classifications: \textit{G23; G32; G34}.

\noindent Keywords: \textit{Keyword 1; Keyword 2.}

\newpage


\section{Introduction}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} % Set back to default
Something here

\subsection{Data}
Something there

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\clearpage
% \section*{Appendices}
% \appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which operating system and which TeX distribution you use. What's the vintage of the TeX distribution. FWIW, I am unable to reproduce the issue you're reporting (unexpected/unwanted footnote symbol) running MacOS 10.12.4 "Sierra" (which provides "Adobe Garamond Pro" as a system font) running either MacTeX2016 or MacTeX2017/pre, under either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 Home, and I am using TeXstudio latest version 2.12.4. On my computer, I installed MikTeX 2.9, and I used XeLaTeX to compile. If I compiled using LuaLaTeX, then there was no symbol at all. When I switched to XeLaTeX, then it came out as an envelop-in-portrait symbol.

Comment: When was the last time you fully updated MikTeX? Does the same issue occur if you switch to LuaLaTeX? (I noticed that your document loads the `selnolig` package, which doesn't actually do any ligature-suppression work unless the document is compiled with LuaLaTeX.)

Comment: I updated MikTex just 3-4 minutes ago. It didn't help either under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. However, if I uncommented the code that begins from "\usepackage[]{mathdesign}" to "\usepackage[english]{selnolig}", and switched to pdfLaTeX, then the symbol is back to normal, i.e., an asterisk.

Comment: If I ran the code under LuaLaTeX, then the symbol is missing, i.e., no symbol as a superscript to the right of "Title", and in the footnote, there is no symbol, just "We thank ABC...".

Comment: Your document works fine for me, but "funny symbols" (xelatex) and "missing symbols" (lualatex) indicates a problem with the actual font. How did you get the Garamond? Which font is loaded at the end of the lualatex.log?

Comment: Please try to re-run your code (under XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX) using `EB Garamond` instead of `Adobe Garamond Pro`. If the problem behavior vanishes, the cause of the problem must be in the system font file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I downloaded the font from this website http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Adobe-Garamond-Pro-Regular . At the end of the lualatex.log is this error message: "mathdesign.sty" warning line 175 No font specified

Comment: @Mico: If I used EB Garamond, it just kept running like forever, so I always had to press ESC to quit.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm all out of ideas: It's either something in your OS setup (in particular, how fonts are handled), your MikTeX setup, or something with `luaotfload` (in case the document is compiled with LuaLaTeX). As Ulrike and I have reported, we're both unable to reproduce the issues you've encountered. Having a nonreproducible error is one of the hardest things to fix...

Comment: @Mico: Thank you for your time and patience. I'll switch back to default font.